# Merge two number with the integers at corresponding position together (without using str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Let's say I have two integers:

```
a = 123
b = 4567
```

I want to merge these numbers keeping the corresponding position of integer at each position together. My desire final number is:

```
1425367
```

But I **don't want to use `str` to achieve this**.

---

Here's the code I have written so far. But it simply disregards the last number.

*Edit: I know I used `str`, but I don't know any other way to achieve this*

````py
def f(a,b):
    sa, sb = list(str(a)), list(str(b))
    i, j = 0, 0
    s = ""
    while i < len(sa) and j < len(sb):
        s += sa[i]
        s += sb[j]
        i += 1
        j += 1
    return s

print(f(23,56))```
````

Comment: you asked for without using `str` but your code is using it

Comment: Yes I want to know how to do it with out using `str`

Comment: FWIW the operation you're trying to do isn't "concatenating" -- that would give you a result like `1234567`.  What  you're doing is interleaving the digits from the two numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Use f-strings instead of `str`, and use `zip_longest` to combine the two strings:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> int(''.join((x or "") + (y or "") for x, y in zip_longest(f"{a}", f"{b}")))
1425367
```

If you have some "no imports" rule, it's not too much harder to do this with the builtin `zip`, but you need to special-case the trailing digits:

```
>>> int(''.join((x or "") + (y or "") for x, y in zip(f"{a}", f"{b}")) + f"{a}")[len(f"{b}"):] + f"{b}"[len(f"{a}"):]
1425367
```

Comment: still being a str type, needs to be a int type.

Comment: ah it's not clear what actual type the OP wants this to be in -- if it's supposed to be an `int` at the end, wrap the whole thing in `int` and you've still done it without using the `str` operator.  :P

Comment: the final result to be converted to int

Comment: If you wanted to do this without involving any string conversion at all, you can do that by writing a function that explodes a string into a list of digits, and another function that re-assembles the list in to a single int.  This is literally just rewriting the string/int conversion functions though so it's not like it's any more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach without any form of `string` or `fstrings`. A pure numeric approach -

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def get_pos_nums(num):
    pos_nums = []
    while num != 0:
        pos_nums.append((num % 10))
        num = num // 10
    return list(reversed(pos_nums))

zipped = zip_longest(get_pos_nums(a), get_pos_nums(b))
digits = [i for j in zipped for i in j if i!=None]
number = sum(d * 10**i for i, d in enumerate(digits[::-1]))
```

```
1425367
```

1. The first function breaks a number into its digits by dividing by 10
2. Next zip_longest zips the 2 lists in the order provided, giving None if one of the strings runs out of digits.
3. Flatten this list of digits and remove the Nones
4. Combine them with a sum after multiplying each with power of 10s

Comment: OP asked for the answer to be `1425367`, so they don't actually want the digits to be concatenated, but rather interleaved.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this solution? Is there any way to do this without using numpy? I also want them to be "interlaced" not just added next to each other

Comment: @lolnoname, just working on a fix. I though you wanted to append a and b. instead of zipping them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to achieve this without using string (or *f-string*):

1. Create a function to split your numbers into list of integers
2. Merge list of both the integers containing corresponding numbers together
3. Join the numbers in the list using multiplication by 10 to get desired final number

**Step 1: Split number to list of integers**

Created custom function using `math.log10()` which returns the list of integers from given string

```
from math import log10

def get_num_left_to_right(num):
    n = int(log10(num))
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        fac = 10**i
        x = num//fac
        yield x
        num -= x * fac
```

Sample run:

```
a, b = 123, 4567

x = list(get_num_left_to_right(a))
# where `x` holds:
# [1, 2, 3]

y = list(get_num_left_to_right(b))
# where `y` holds:
# [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

**Step 2: Merge both the lists with corresponding number together**

I am using `itertools.chain` and `itertools.izip_longest` along with *list comprehension* to achieve this. For example:

```
from itertools import izip_longest, chain

num_list = [x for x in chain(*izip_longest(x, y)) if x is not None]
# where `num_list` will hold:
# [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

**Step 3: Multiply the number in list by the power of 10**

Finally, I am multiply the numbers in the list by the `10**(length-i-1)` to get the desired position of integer in the final number

```
num, length = 0, len(num_list)

for i, n in enumerate(num_list):
    num += n*10**(length-i-1)

# where `num` will be holding:
# 14253670
```